# Using "get to" rather than "arrive at"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, verbs, adverbial-phrases

Is this a grammatically and syntactically correct sentence?

> When you have got to at home you have to get on with the work straight away.

I want to say when a person arrived at home he has to proceed with his work immediately.

Comment: If you want to say *arrive*, why don't you say it? *When you **arrive** at home you have to get on with the work straight away*. Why have you replaced *arrive* with *have got to*?

Comment: @Jason Bassford Thank you for the answer. I've changed it because I'm learning **get to** form. I don't understand what is the difference between **get to** and **arrive**

Comment: You can *get to* a place or you can *arrive at* a place. But while they essentially mean the same thing, the syntax around them is different. In your example sentence, *when you **arrive (at)** home* would be replaced by *when you **get** home*. (*When you **get home** you have to get on with the work straight away.*)

Comment: @Jason Bassford It is more clear now. Thanks a lot

Comment: More idiomatically: *You must start work as soon as you [get home](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+get+home).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you *get to* a place or you *arrive at* a place.

So, both of the following would be acceptable:

> ✔ When you have **got to** the mall . . .
>   ✔ When you have **arrived at** the mall . . .

But the combination of *both* prepositions isn't used:

> ✘ When you have **got to at** the mall . . .
>   ✘ When you have **arrived at to** the mall . . .

---

The same is true when using *home*, but with the caveat that, unlike other nouns, a preposition is normally not used with it. (This is because the meaning of [*home*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home) is more nuanced than most other nouns—perhaps because of its additional adjectival sense.)

So, we would have the following:

> ✔ When we have got <sup>to</sup> home . . .
>   ✔ When we have arrived <sup>at</sup> home . . .

Sometimes, a preposition is used, but it's not as common. It's also less common to see *got to home* than it is to see *arrived at home*. (I can't explain why this is the case.)

In summary:

> ✔ When you have got home . . .
>   ？ When you have got **to** home . . .
>   ✘ When you have got **to at** home . . .

The first sentence is fine, the second is syntactically okay (but might sound strange to some people), and the third is ungrammatical (it's never used).

---

As a more general comment, changing the tenses used in the example sentence would result in a more natural expression:

> When you *get home* you *will* have to get on with the work straight away.